# ExpressionEngine & Expresso - How to check if product was added to cart after return

Tags: ee2, expresso, related-entries, shopping-cart

I am using Expresso with ExpressionEngine.  I was wondering if there is a way to know what product was just added to the cart on return after the product is successfully added to the cart?  I could add the {entry_id} to the end of the return parameter but was hoping there was a cleaner way of doing this.

What I am looking to do is that after a product is added to the cart I want to display a modal window with some related accessories to the product that was just added to the cart.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a quick test and it appears Exp:resso cart show the most recently added item last in the cart items list so you could use the {if item:count == item:total_results} variable to do stuff, you may be able to use that to trigger your modal window...

```
{items}
  {!-- output titles of items in cart __}   
  {title} 

  {!-- if the last item do something here --}
  {if item:count == item:total_results}
  TRIGGER SOMETHING
  {/if}

{/items}
```

Comment: That would work with one exception.  If I add a product on return I could use that code and display the related products, exactly what I wanted but if I come back to the same product after browsing some other pages I would then get the related products again since that would still be the last item added to the cart.  Maybe I could add some other parameter on the url, like success or something to signify a success add to cart and just check the specific segment for the value, which I think is better than putting the entry_id on the url.